# How to render a HTML file and return a string at same time

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am using flask for backend and javascript(and HTML) for front .
How can I render a HTML file and return  a string to the same HTML file at the same time in flask .

Currently I am returning from flask as following :

```
return render_template('index.html')
```

Edited : Actually I want to render a "index.html" while returning from flask server to front end . At the same time I have a string in the backend that will be used in the rendered HTML file (lets say string is a filename called str-"myfile.txt") . So Now I will be able to use this string in front end .

One way would be :

```
return render_template('index.html', desired_string=string ) {backend}

var mystring = {{ desired_string | safe}} {front end }
```

But here I get following error  :

> uploader:282 Uncaught ReferenceError: Input_reorderedcolor is not
>   defined

here Input_reorderedcolor is actually string I am returning

Comment: I don't get it ;) could you elaborate a bit more

Comment: I don't get too. can you explain your problem? @danish

Comment: Actually I want to render a "index.html" while returning from flask server to front end . At the same time I have a string in the backend that will be used in the rendered HTML file (lets say string is a filename called str-"myfile.txt") . So Now I will be able to use this string in front end .

Comment: I have editted with better explanation :)

Comment: You have an unquoted string. That's invalid JavaScript. `{{ desired_string|tojson|safe }}` will handle converting the Jinja variable to its JavaScript equivalent.

Comment: @dirn Thanks alot , it worked :D